# Anchor event type on typescript

Tags: anchor, typescript

How do I declare a variable to be of a certain Anchor event type? In general, I am not sure how to extract a subtype within the program idl

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for a way to declare a variable as being of the type of an Anchor event from the IDL? If that's the case then it's not currently possible. I have an open issue on the Anchor repo here you might want to follow: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2050

> In general, I am not sure how to extract a subtype within the program idl

To answer this more broadly, there are some helpers in Anchor. For example you can use `type AccountName = IdlAccounts<IDLType>['accountName']` to get an account. See docs here: https://coral-xyz.github.io/anchor/ts/index.html#IdlAccounts